# Convert a long string of date and time into Timestamp format in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

I recently received an unlabeled field in the metadata I'm working with.

The data in it all looks like this:

```
20160305111235.703000

20101030120530.703000
```

I suspect that they are just a long string made by date and time combined.

The best way in order to work with these strings in my project seems to be converting such strings to the Timestamp format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"

Is there an good way to convert to this format?  I am using substring to add the "-" and ":" to the string, but is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later: [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddkkmmss.SSSSSS") ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20160305111235.703000", formatter);
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println(ldt);
```

> 2016-03-05T11:12:35.703

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to do it. There is description by link. Also you can google for a lot of examples how to use it.

So you just need to convert value in your data to `Date` and then format it using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: FYI, the old `SimpleDateFormat`,  [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque [still about equal with java7](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/java-version-and-vendor-data-analyzed-2016-edition)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).